# Regex that match each word in a string regardless of space or hyphen?

Tags: ruby, regex

I thought this question could be interesting to put it up here.

For example I have a string for search query like: `"hello world"`

There could be strings like this:

```
Hello World
Hello-world
hello!! world
```

How could you write an expression that will dynamically match these? If the expression works, it should works on this too:

```
Search: "Hi pals!"

Hi pals
Hi! Pals!
Hi-pals
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could do something like this:

```
/hi.*?pals/i
```

the trailing `i` at the end enables case-insensitive matching, and the `.*?` matches any characters (except line breaks) between the `"hi"` and `"pals"`.

A Rubular demo: http://rubular.com/r/cwtbV2iTwy

Beware that it also matches a string like "Himalaya pals":

```
Himalaya pals
^^       ^^^^
```

If you don't want that to happen, add some word-boundaries in the mix:

```
/\bhi\b.*?\bpals\b/i
```

Comment: is there a way to make it dynamic? this will definitely not match hello world

Comment: Well, you can do it like this: `/hi.*?pals|hello.*?world/i` to match both of the two greetings. Not sure what you mean by _dynamic_ though...

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you don't want "hi pals" to match "chi palsy", either, right? Seems like you're trying to find strings that have the same words as your input. If so, here's a way:

```
class String
  def words
    scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase)
  end
end

a = ["Hi pals", "Hi, pals", "hi-pals", "hi! ? pals?", "hipals", "himalaya pals"]
search = "hi pals"

a.select {|test| test.words == search.words}

=> ["Hi pals", "Hi, pals", "hi-pals", "hi! ? pals?"]
```