# Match full word regardless of capitalization or complex spacing

Tags: java, regex

I have a project wherein I'm meant to match all instances of a word in a job advert, taken from the [GitHub Jobs API](https://jobs.github.com/api).

I've been playing around with [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/), but I know that it's not specific to Java.

How can I use Java-specific RegEx to match instances of the "head" word in the following code, regardless of capitalization or complex word spacing, i.e. `Cloud computing`.

```
Python(Code.advanced_computing, "python", "(python)"),
AdvancedComputing(Code.advanced_computing, "advanced computing", "(advanced computing)"),
Programming(Code.advanced_computing, "programming", "(programming)"),
ComputationalSystems(Code.advanced_computing, "computational systems", "(computational systems)"),
Coding(Code.advanced_computing, "coding", "(coding)"),
CloudComputing(Code.advanced_computing, "Cloud computing", "(\\Cloud computing)"),
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888647/regex-that-match-each-word-in-a-string-regardless-of-space-or-hyphen?rq=1), the following should work, however, that is not the case:

```
Python(Code.advanced_computing, "python", "(/python/i)"),
AdvancedComputing(Code.advanced_computing, "advanced computing", "(/advanced.*?computing/i)"),
Programming(Code.advanced_computing, "programming", "(programming)"),
ComputationalSystems(Code.advanced_computing, "computational systems", "(/computational.*?systems/i)"),
Coding(Code.advanced_computing, "coding", "(/coding/i)"),
CloudComputing(Code.advanced_computing, "Cloud computing", "(/cloud.*?computing/i)"),
```

Comment: See [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/1945631). If you have a specific problem then show us what you have tried, describe why it doesn't work and what you would expect it to do. See "[ask]" and [this checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use case insensitive matching in Java you have to include `(?i)` in the start of your regex.

Consider the following naive example:

```
String s = "ClOuD ComPuTinG";
if(s.matches("(?i)cloud.*computing")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH"); // will print MATCH
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT");
}

if(s.matches("cloud.*computing")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT"); // will print NOT
}
```

For more details take a look at [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/case_insensitive_matching_in_java) article about case insensitive  matching in java.

**Update**

Furthermore, you don't have to write the regex inside `/` in Java.

So the line

```
CloudComputing(Code.advanced_computing, "Cloud computing", "(/cloud.*?computing/i)")
```

should be

```
CloudComputing(Code.advanced_computing, "Cloud computing", "(?i)cloud.*computing")
```

The `.*` is the correct expression to match any number of characters. This means that you will also match cases like `the clouds are white. I like computing...`. I would use a regex like `(?i)cloud[\s_-]*computing` where `[\s_-]` is a character class of all the empty spaces, undersores and dashes. So, you will match `cloud_computing` or `cloud-_-_---_    computing` but not the previous sentence.